# How do you update the maxFeatures setting of a WFS layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, update

I have a WFS layer which a protocol in the definition. The protocol states that the maxFeatures returned should be 1 to avoid downloading a large amount of data.

I can update the value for maxFeatures using layer.protocol.maxFeatures and this registers as updating successfully but when I then call a layer.refress({force:true}); command the actual WFS request still appears to be limited to 1.

Is there a good example of how to modify a WFS protocol using javascript once the layer has already been loaded into the map?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have now resolved this issue.

It appears that the maxFeatures setting is under layer.protocol.options.maxFeatures.

I now have two references but updating both has the desired impact.